# Why is my texture breaking when I move my object away from world origin?

Tags: texturing, uv

This is what the textures look like near the world origin:

[image]

If I move the object in any direction, at some point the texture goes from fine to "broken", it looks like this:

[image]

[image]

I've tried applying the modifier, applying the scales, tweaking things with the textures coordinates, but I couldn't find anything conclusive.

[Here is the blend file](https://fex.net/s/nrnmmx7) if you want to have a look, note that the eyes were generated using Human Generator addon.
Thank you.

Comment: Hello, it doesn't seem to change anything to move the object, what is the XYZ location where it happens?

Comment: @moonboots It starts at ``X: 0`` ``Y: -7.9914`` ``Z: 1.6757``

Comment: ok, that's weird because it works fine for me

Comment: Graphics gard error ? what if you close the file and open again ?

Comment: Your file weighs 160 MB... Was it really not possible to prepare a file showcasing your problem, that weighs a couple megabytes instead?

Comment: @Emir I tried that. It's also visible in the final result if I render the frame.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I know it's heavy, i'm sorry but I literally created a new project file -> created a character model with Human Generator addon -> removed everything but the eyes -> packed the textures. And that gives me a 160MB file, surely there are things that aren't being deleted when I delete the character parts but I don't know what. Either way, could it be an issue with the addon? Maybe it's only visible if you have it installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be some bug in `v3.0.0` & `v3.0.1`, upgrading to `v3.1` or higher fixed the problem